# How to get value of key up event on angular chosen select

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angular-chosen

I'm using angular chosen select, which is named localytics.directives module, and I want to set a key up event into this select input,How can I get this value?Thanks!

```
       <select chosen
                  ng-change="vm.fixItem(matchedLevel,unresolved)"
                  disable-search="false"
                  ng-model="matchedLevel"
                  ng-options="matchedLevel as matchedLevel.Name for
                  matchedLevel in level.allLevelItems">
      </select>
```

Comment: Please provide some code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code inside your chosen directives linker function

```
$(".chosen-container").unbind('keyup').bind('keyup',function(e) {
                    //console.log('sfddf');
                    var searchStr = $('.chosen-container .search-field input').val();
                    console.log(searchStr);
                });
```